# Is it possible to model jQuery.fn.extend using TypeScript

Tags: jquery, typescript

My guess is that the answer to this is "no" but I wanted to check there wasn't something I'd missed.

jQuery has a [fn.extend method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fn.extend/) which allows you to augment the jQuery object with extra methods.  Here's an example from the API docs:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
  check: function() {
    return this.each(function() {
      this.checked = true;
    });
  },
  uncheck: function() {
    return this.each(function() {
      this.checked = false;
    });
  }
});

// Use the newly created .check() method
$( "input[type='checkbox']" ).check();
```

I've been filling out the jQuery JSDoc and tests for the [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/jquery) project.  Previously jQuery.fn was defined as `any`.  To bring it in line with the docs I've been looking at changing it to cover the `extend` method:

```
fn: {
    /**
     * Merge the contents of an object onto the jQuery prototype to provide new jQuery instance methods.
     * 
     * @param object An object to merge onto the jQuery prototype.
     */
    extend(object: any): any;
}
```

However, I don't think there's a way in TypeScript to model the *dynamic* rather than *static* augmentation of methods.  This means it's not possible to subsequently use these dynamically augmented methods in your TS unless you either:

1. cast jQuery to `any` or
2. use bracket notation like `$("input[type='checkbox']")["check"]();`

So my question: is there something I've missed?  Is there a better way to model `jQuery.fn` so TypeScript can pick up that `jQueryStatic` gets assigned these dynamic methods?  As I say, I think the answer is "no" but I wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a definitive no.

It would be nice to execute code in the compiler inside the definition but no such syntax exists. This is what I wish it had:

```
interface Foo{
   bar(member:any):any @ execute { // execute this code inside the compiler language service:
       var keys = compiler.getArgs().keys();
       compiler.getIdentifier('JQueryStatic').addMembers /// you get the point.
   }
}
```

But it has the potential of making the compilation slow, and would be full of edge cases, not to mention its more work that isn't on the table I presume.

Comment: Cheers for that Bas. It's much as I expected but worth checking I thought.

Comment: A related feature request `contract programming` : https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/700